# ConTeXt : combine fonts

Tags: fonts, context

I would like to create a font that uses palatino (or pagella) for the text but euler for the math. If I understand correctly the documentation, it should be achievable with typefaces, but I can't get it to working : all the text is in Latin. Here is a MWE inspired from the doc :

```
\starttypescript [perso] [texnansi, ec, qx, t5, default]
  \definetypeface[perso] [rm] [Xserif] [palatino] [default]
  \definetypeface[perso] [tt] [Xmono] [palatino] [default]
  \definetypeface[perso] [mm] [Xmath] [euler] [default]
\stoptypescript

\starttext

\setupbodyfont[perso]
Bonjour les ami·e·s
\startformula
  x + 3 = \mathcal{P}
\stopformula

\setupbodyfont[palatino]
Bonjour les ami·e·s
\startformula
  x + 3 = \mathcal{P}
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried `\setupbodyfont[euleroverpagella]` or `\setupbodyfont[pagellaovereuler]`?  If none of them fit your needs, you can look in the file `type-imp-euler.mkiv` and see how that was done and make your own typescript file (better leave that one without modification and add your own locally).

Comment: Each of them have the same behavior and switches all pagella for latin…

Comment: I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R80jl.png). No Latin Modern.

Comment: Well, maybe there's a problem with my distribution, but its a standalone… However the pagella-with-euler works here. I really don't understand, but at least it works

Comment: @mickep The `pagellaovereuler` appears to be "Euler Math" for the body text and "Pagella Math" for the math, but I'm not sure why anyone would ever want that. A bug maybe, or just a weird Hans experiement?

Comment: @MaxChernoff I agree that it is weird. I can talk to Hans about it. (I think these can be seen as some left overs from somebody who wanted to mix these fonts in various ways a long time ago.)

Comment: (I might also use the wrong names, maybe `euler-with-pagella` and `pagella-with-euler` are the ones one should use...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to create a font that uses palatino (or pagella) for the text but euler for the math.

ConTeXt already has a builtin solution for this:

```tex
\setupbodyfont[pagella-with-euler]

\startTEXpage
    Euler's Formula: $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]

Regarding the code you posted:

> ```tex
> \starttypescript [perso] [texnansi, ec, qx, t5, default]  
>   \definetypeface[perso] [rm] [Xserif] [palatino] [default]  
>   \definetypeface[perso] [tt] [Xmono] [palatino] [default]  
>   \definetypeface[perso] [mm] [Xmath] [euler] [default]
> \stoptypescript
>
> \starttext
>
> \setupbodyfont[perso]
> ```

1. Listing the encodings is deprecated for almost a decade now.
2. You should use `serif` instead of `Xserif`, and `mono` instead of `Xmono`, … .
3. ConTeXt doesn't define a font with the name `euler`, so you need to actually use `eulernova` (which is essentially the same thing).
4. `\setupbodyfont` is best before `\starttext` (to prevent loading the LM fallback font).

So:

```tex
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]

\starttypescript [perso]
    \definetypeface[perso] [rm] [serif] [palatino]  [default]
    \definetypeface[perso] [tt] [mono]  [palatino]  [default]
    \definetypeface[perso] [mm] [math]  [eulernova] [default]
\stoptypescript
\setupbodyfont[perso]

\starttext
    Bonjour les ami·e·s

    \startformula
    x + 3 = \mathcal{P}
    \stopformula
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I think `eulernova` at some point changed name into `euler-math`. (But maybe not in the typescripts... Sorry)

Comment: @mickep Yeah, `type-imp-euler.mkxl:26--29` has (essentially) `\starttypescript[eulernova] \definefontsynonym[Serif][file:euler-math.otf] \stoptypescript`. I guess a `euler -> eulernova` alias should probably be added, similar to the current `palatino -> pagella`

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear ! I don't know why pagella-euler, pagellaovereuler and euleroverpagella didn't work on my computer, but pagella-with-euler does. However the math symbols behave strangely : I edit the OP to show the problem.

Comment: Please don't change the question in case this answered your problem as stated. Better then ask a new question and refer to this one.

Comment: Ok, I cancel the edit and open a new subject